# Macro alternative for __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, trace

I have a class, `Logger`, which of course is for logging. It is a singleton class, accessed by static member functions. So, for example:

```
Logger::Warning("something");
```

Great. Then I added an overload function to do tracing, so:

```
Logger::Warning(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, "something");
```

Now, that seemed a bit long so I defined a macro:

```
#define TRACE __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__
```

so that the code now looks like

```
Logger::Warning(TRACE, "something");
```

Still seemed like I could do better, so now a new macro:

```
#define LOG_WARNING(...) Logger::Warning(__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

And we have:

```
LOG_WARNING("somthing");
```

So that works, but here is my question:

Is there a way to accomplish this WITHOUT using a macro? It seems to me that `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__func__` need to be used in the actual function of interest, and thus a macro is required. And please don't suggest `debug_backtrace()`.